# R2D3's QUnit tests fail out of the box - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, raphael, qunit

I've just checked out [R2D3](https://github.com/mhemesath/r2d3/) from github, and now I want to run the tests. I am new to this repo, and not an expert on JS testing, but *think* the correct way to do this is to look at [tests/index.html](https://github.com/mhemesath/r2d3/blob/master/tests/index.html) in a web browser, and see whether the QUnit tests pass.

However, when I try to do this, 41 out of 52 tests fail straight out of the box (in Chrome, Firefox and Safari on OSX):

[image]

I can see from developer tools that all the files are loading correctly, so it isn't just that a path is wrong. Looking at the code suggests that `.append()` is failing. The first two errors are at [line 16](https://github.com/mhemesath/r2d3/blob/master/tests/core/append-tests.js#L16) in `tests/core/append-tests.js`: `var el = svg.append('image')` and [line 20](https://github.com/mhemesath/r2d3/blob/master/tests/core/append-tests.js#L20): `var el = svg.append('line')`.

Tracing the problem [back to the root in `r2d3.v2.js`](https://github.com/mhemesath/r2d3/blob/master/r2d3.v2.js#L12946), it seems to be these two functions that are the problem:

```
Raphael.fn.appendChild = function(childNode) {
  var node = this.buildElement(childNode);
  if (node) {
    this.shadowDom.appendChild(childNode);
    node.updateStyle(); //  Apply CSS styles
  }
  return node;
};
Raphael.fn.buildElement = function(childNode) {
  var type = childNode && childNode.nodeName,
      node =  type ? this[type.toLowerCase()]() : null;

  if (node) {
    // Ensure Paper can be referenced from sets
    node.shadowDom = childNode
    node.parentNode = this;
    // Link the shadowDOM node by the Raphael id.
    node.shadowDom.r2d3 = true;
    node.shadowDom.r2d3id = r2d3UID();
    node.paper = this;
    node.tagName = type.toLowerCase();
        node.style = new ElementStyle(node);

    r2d3Elements[node.shadowDom.r2d3id] = node;
  }
  return node;
}
```

However, my ability to debug goes no further. Can anyone suggest what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are running the qunit tests with Chrome. R2D3 is built for IE only.

Comment: Duhhhhh! Thank you. I'll install an IE VM and try it out.